# RecordCont returns the pointer to current record and not the number frecords

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on access 2003. 
In a routine called by a click in Form button , i tried to retrive the result of a query
an make some operation with them.
In every place ( also MS online documentation) is explained that to
retrive the number of record in a recordset u must use RecordCount metod on recordset instance.
I wonder why executing the following code I obtain the number of the current position of the cursor;
also, why the record set is not filtered ?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Query42")
Dim IdImp As Integer
Dim x As Integer

x = rs.RecordCount 'x= 1 (rs pints to the first record)

rs.Filter = "[IdImp]= 125 "

' I move to first and then to last
' to understend what happens in the recordset and to make some test on RecordCount
 rs.MoveFirst   
 x = rs.RecordCount 'x= 1 (rs points to the first record)
 rs.MoveLast    
 x = rs.RecordCount 'x= 1234 (rs points to the last record)
 ' so to have recordCount= number of records i must first execute move.last...?
```

I don't work vary much on vbasic , but somtimes i'd like to use acces for simple and rapid develop personal database, but oftne it  lokks to make lose a lot of time...
Tankyyou for any help..

Answer (score 0):

`RecordCount` returns the number of records accessed so far.  Use the `MoveLast` method before calling `RecordCount` to ensure all the records are loaded before you count.

For the filter, either set it before opening the recordset, or reopen the recordset after setting the filter:

```
rs.Filter = "[IdImp] = 125"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Query42")
```

or

```
rs.Filter = "[IdImp] = 125"
rs.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: I tried an seems to work. To get the number of records I must youse MoveLast, and the RecordCount. But to filter i have to create a new RecordSet  Set rsB=rs.OpenRecordset, and then use it.

Comment: Try setting the filter before opening the recordset.